# explosion spritesheet is not working

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I want to do a simple explosion on a collision.Here is my code...

```
public explosion(Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition)
    {
        texture = newTexture;
        position = newPosition;
        timer = 0f;
        interval = 40f;
        currentFrame = 1;
        spriteWidth = 60;
        spritHeight = 60;
        isVisible = true;
    }


public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        if (timer > interval)
        {
            currentFrame++;
            timer = 0f;
        }
        if (currentFrame == 32)
        {
            isVisible = false;
            currentFrame = 0;
        }
        sourceRect = new Rectangle(currentFrame * spriteWidth, 0, spriteWidth, spritHeight);
        origin = new Vector2(sourceRect.Width/2, sourceRect.Height / 2);
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        if (isVisible == true)
        {

            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, sourceRect, Color.White, 0f, origin,1.0f, SpriteEffects.None,0);

        }
    }
```

during collision I am loading like this--

```
foreach (Enemy e in this.em.Enemies)
                {
                    if (i.BoundingRectangle.Intersects(e.BoundingRectangle))
                    {
                        explList.Add(new explosion(cm.Load<Texture2D>("Exp"), new Vector2(e.position.X, e.position.Y)));
                        e.OnHit();
                    }
                }
```

problem is instead of appearing one by one frames,frames are moving to the right side one by one in the rectangle.I am totally new to XNA .Pls help...........

Comment: "Not working" is an insufficient description. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment so I have to do this as an answer.
Tried your code and it worked perfectly for me.

Is the sprite you want to draw really 60x60? If not then that is the problem. Your program is taking rectangles of 60x60. If your sprite is smaller than that then your rectangle will also draw a piece of the next sprite.
If your sprites are bigger than 60x60 then your sprite will not fit into the rectangle and the part that didn't fit into the rectangle will be in the next currentFrame.

If you don't know how to check your sprite size, then upload your spritesheet somewhere so someone can check for you.

If the above is not the case then I'm wondering if you are using XNA or MonoGame. 
Or how show how you call the draw (including the spriteBatch.Begin() function).